# any anchors can't be pressed in one of my divs

Tags: html, css, z-index

In one of my divs neither anchors nor forms work properly. They are displayed the way they are supposed to, but I can't press them at all, they behave just like usual text/picture.
This div needed to have a transparent div above it (and a non-transparent text above above it), so I set its `z-index` to be `-2`.

```
div{
  position: relative;
  z-index:-2;
}
```

Now, when I delete `z-index: -2`, anchors and forms can be pressed. But that way my transparency system ruins.

How do I make my anchors and input forms clickable without getting rid of `z-index` property? And what is the possible reason for `z-index` destroying anchor's functionality?

Comment: Negative z-indexes are almost never the right answer to a problem.

Comment: remove `z-index:-2` . you are putting your content under everything else.

Comment: You could't click the div cause it is under the transparent layout. So whenever you tried to click the div you were actually clicking the transparent layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have non-transparent div, above which lies transparent div, above which lies non-transparent div text with anchors, I needed to have **z-indexes with such values**:

```
div.transparent::after{
    content: '';
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

div.non-transparent{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Neither positive nor negative values worked for non-transparent div (in a sense that with positive z-indexes I had transparency disappear and with negatives I had my anchors non-clickable).

Answer (score 1):

Having a negative `z-index` automatically removes it's ability to be clicked, because it is essentially saying this is below the actual surface. It's like looking through a glass wall.

The alternative and proper solution is to increase the z-index of the other elements such that they are placed above the element you need to be behind them.

In essence, always go up, not down, with z-indices.

(Note: for a much lengthier and in-depth answer try checking out [this article from Smashing](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/).)

Comment: But that ruins my transparency system. I want to have non-transparent div, above which lies transparent div, above which lies non-transparent text with anchors. This only works with negative indexes apparently (I just tried to invert my indexes to positives values).

Comment: Thanks for help, I figured it out.